# show.html.erb and html tags in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem about accessing posts/show.html.erb

i can list all posts on index.html.erb but when i try to access any
post, html tags are not shown in show.html.erb, like images, they are dissapearing.

**My Controlller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :postu_belirt, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show

  end


  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

private

def postu_belirt
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_parametreleri
    params.require(:post).permit(:baslik,:text)
end

end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= link_to post.baslik, post, :class => "baslik"%>
<%= post.created_at.strftime("%d %b %y") %>
<%= post.created_at.strftime("%H:%M") %>
<%= raw post.text %>
<%- end %>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%=  @post.baslik %>
<%=  @post.created_at.strftime("%d %b %y") %>
<%=  @post.created_at.strftime("%H:%M") %>
<%=  link_to 'Duzenle', edit_post_path(@post), :class => "genel" %>
<%=  raw @post.text %>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, that's weird. Did you try replacing the whole contents of your view with some text just to check if it's being loaded?

Comment: now i realized only images are not shown
and i'm using standart html tag for record like  `<img src="assets/asd.jpg" />`

Comment: You should use the `image_tag` helper for images: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: i tried 
`<img src="<%= image_tag ('asd.jpg') %>"  />` and `<%= image_tag ('asd.jpg') %>` both are didnt work. thanks depa.
btw if i put like this `<img src="<%= image_tag ('asd.jpg') %>" />` i can see on index.html.erb